# What would be the best way to generate IDs to make rows individual?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, uniqueidentifier

In order to remove specific rows from a csv file I want to add an ID value to my rows. There are a few ways this could be done of course and I'd appreciate some input on possible ways to generate IDs. Simple and short but good ways are preferred.

Maybe a **random** big number using `random.randint(00000, 99999)` for example? But needing to check for **possible duplicates** would make me think that there is a better solution.

Another way would be to **read the csv** file add `1` to some variable for each line. Maybe you would even need to figure out a way to check that the given line contains actual csv content and isn't just a result of `\n`. I tried this and had success but the code is just really long and ugly.

I bet there are better ways I can't think of. My go at it can be found below. It works for my specific row mangemant and way of adding new lines. That's what I used to this point.

I am looking for a solution for Python 3+ if it wasn't obvious to this point.

```
import os

def ID(filename):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        if os.path.getsize() == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            ID = 1
            [ID += 1 for line in open(filename, "r")]
            return ID
    else:
        return 1
```

Comment: It might be more obvious if you added a few letters to the start of the ID: myID1, myID2, myID3 ...  Adding leading zeros might also make for better readability: myID00001. myID00002 ...

Comment: What is the purpose of these IDs? Knowing this will help determine a suitable or optimal technique.

Comment: @martineau Some small program to add/remove/list entries of, for example, medication you took to keep track of it. Or food/calories. Something like that. That's why a 16 digit key would not be suited well. You should be able to easily remove it via argparse. `--remove 1232` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a v4 UUID

```
import uuid

ID = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

It's random and guaranteed to be unique for most practical applications.

Comment: Since the user should be able to manually remove rows via `--remove <ID>` this would not be ideal, but good to know that module exists.

Comment: @xvx If that's the case, it looks more like you should be using some database engine like sqlite, not a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Counting lines is not a good idea because if you remove a line from the middle of the file and then try to find a new ID, you may end up duplicating a previously-used ID.

If you keep the file sorted by ID, you can just add 1 to the ID of the last line.

Alternatively, you can use [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/uuid.html) to generate identifiers random enough that you don't have to worry about collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be fairly easy to generate unique N-digit random numbers with something like this:

```
import random

_seen = set()
def uniqueID(length):
    while True:
        v = int(''.join(str(random.randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(length)))
        if v not in _seen:
            _seen.add(v)
            return v

for _ in range(10):
    print(uniqueID(16))
```